# Confirm Submit Popup or Checkbox

Tags: popup

I have a form that can't be edited after submission and there are users who write in a support ticket to ask to amend the details submitted.

3 possible choices as I can think of are;

1. Just a line above the submit button that tells users to check
   the details and it can't be edited after it's submitted.
2. Checkbox labeled with "I confirm I submitting the correct information and I can't edit them later on".
3. Popup that asks "Confirm submission? You can't edit the details after submit it".

What's your thoughts about each one other and possible alternatives to them?

Answer (score 1):

#### You need a confirm page, not popup.

Just like how you would go to a confirm page of an order in a checkout process. If there are more steps in the process show some progress steps that allow going back and forth in the process.

Everything you mentioned is good to have. Show all details of what is going to be submitted, in your case the whole support ticket and some other details maybe. A clear message that this is how it will be submitted and that it can't be changed afterwards can be combined with a checkbox so people can't say they simply read over it. As mentioned above it is important to have an easy way back to edit the ticket otherwise no alert or checkbox is going to stop people from just submitting it.

[image]